# Ionic Date object locked to GMT on Android 7.1.1 (API 25)

Tags: android, date, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm making a cross-platform app using Ionic, and one of the things I have to do is schedule some notifications. On iOS this process works perfectly, but for some reason in the Android simulator it insists on using GMT+0000 as the timezone, even though that is not correct. (Namely, `new Date()` turns into `DD MM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss GMT+0000 (GMT)`, when it should be using my local timezone.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I should mention, the time zone is correctly set on the simulator (both the status bar clock and the settings app confirm this).

EDIT 2: It only happens on Android 7.1.1 (API 25). API 24 and 26 both work correctly, but for some unknown reason 25 refuses to give the timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was simply using outdated plugins. I updated everything and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

First you should probably write your application to be able to handle different time zones. including GMT.

Here it looks like your emulator phone is set to GMT time zone. go to Android settings on your emulator and change it to the timezone you want to test in.

Comment: The app is set up to handle different timezones, but for some reason any new `Date` object in Android is insisting that it's in GMT. Also, as mentioned in my edit, the device has the timezone set correctly. It's only Ionic/Cordova that's having issues.